# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null in JUnit test using eclipse

Tags: junit, null, assertion

I'm new to JUnit and am trying to get some tests running. I have the following codes. After running the codes the test failed and shows AssertionFailedError: null

```
  package com.seleniumsimplified.webdriver;
  import org.junit.Test;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
  import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;

  public class FirstTest {

  @Test
  public void driverIsTheKing(){

      WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(); 
      driver.get("http://www.compendiumdev.co.uk/selenium");

      assertTrue(driver.getTitle().startsWith("Selenium simplified") );
  }

}
```

This test always fails in the last line and the stacktrace is the following

```
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:27)
at com.seleniumsimplified.webdriver.FirstTest.driverIsTheKing(FirstTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
assertTrue(driver.getTitle().startsWith("Selenium simplified") );
```

It seems the title is something else.

Try to output the actual title and see what you get.

```
String title = driver.getTitle()
assertTrue(title, title.startsWith("Selenium simplified") );
```

(I wish there was a assertStartWith that does this automatically, just like assertEqual does).

Comment: @ Thilo thanks for the response, i have output the actual title, which is 'Selenium Simplified - a book and ebook on Automated Web Testing with Java and Selenium RC'. The JUnit test now passed after editing the title. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: how ever, the test still fails if StartsWith(Selenium simplified") is used in the code. Errors: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Selenium Simplified - a book and ebook on Automated Web Testing with Java and Selenium RCat junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
 at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
 at com.seleniumsimplified.webdriver.FirstTest.driverIsTheKing(FirstTest.java:25)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source

Comment: because you have a capital S in Simplified. startsWith is case sensitive.